# Using raw SQL command like LIKE

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I would like to use raw SQL command to do a query.

```
engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
```

My table name is `books` and `title` is a column in it. I have got the value of `detail` from a form.

```
detail=request.form.get("detail")
book=db.execute("SELECT title FROM books WHERE title = :detail",{"detail":detail})
```

What i want is to run this query with `LIKE` command such that I can have title as LIKE detail, that is, I want something like:

```
book=db.execute("SELECT title FROM books WHERE title LIKE *:detail*",{"detail":detail})
```

to have value of title to be comprising of characters of detail and some characters before and after denoted by * as wildcards.
Could you help me to achieve this, remember I want to use **raw SQL commands only**.

Comment: (1) Use `%` instead of `*` as your wildcard character. (2) Include the wildcard characters in the parameter value, not in the command text.

Comment: Here're examples of that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51463912/cs50-like-operator-variable-substitution-with-expansion